# SQL: Selecting current month last year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I currently select data from the current month **LAST** year. This works fine with

```
SELECT cast(CREATED as date) AS DATE, COUNT([ID]) AS BOOKINGS, SUM([TOTCOST]) AS Sales
from BOOKING
WHERE
CREATED >= DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-12, 0)
AND
CREATED < DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-11, 0)
GROUP BY cast(CREATED as date)
ORDER BY cast(CREATED as date)
```

However, rather than return 1st to 31st July, I would like to return 2nd July 2014 to 1st August 2014 inclusive. So effectivly +1 day on that current month.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply add 1 to the result of your calculation.

```
SELECT cast(CREATED as date) AS DATE, COUNT([ID]) AS BOOKINGS, SUM([TOTCOST]) AS Sales
from BOOKING
WHERE
CREATED >= (DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-12, 0) + 1)
AND
CREATED < (DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-11, 0) + 1)
GROUP BY cast(CREATED as date)
ORDER BY cast(CREATED as date)
```